# file_put_contents in other subfolder

Tags: php, shell

Let's say i create this this file in php

```
<?php
echo file_put_contents("test.txt","Hello World. Testing!");
?>
```

and i have this structure

- domain/App
- domain/Files
- domain/OtherFolders

the file is getting created from a php which is inside /App folder.. i can create in public html (one directory back) with this

```
<?php
echo file_put_contents("../test.txt","Hello World. Testing!");
?>
```

but i cant create it in the other folder domain/Files. How is that possible ?

Both Folders are owned from the same domain and yes i've tried and with whole url and its not working... i'm thinking of only sollution is to copy the file in main directory and then maybe move it somehow to the next folder..

Comment: Have you set the permissions right for those folders?

Comment: Is the other folder "domain/Files" owned by www-data? The page will run your command but if the folder isn't owned by www-data it will fail because of permissions. Sometimes it's worth putting the full path to the directory aswell.